# An event function occurs automatically without any event being fired

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener, event-listener, keyboard-events

Creating a JavaScript snake game using very a beginner approach. I am using the `KeyboardEvent.key`  property 
When i fire an event ( let's say pressing the ArrowUp key ). My snake goes towards that direction, but once i press another key ( let's say pressing the ArrowDown key  ) at every intervals ( i used `setTimeout()` as the game counter) the snake goes up and down. i.e the ArrowUp key press event hasn't been removed.

```js
//GAME BOARD
var nodeList = document.getElementById('game-board')
let children = nodeList.childNodes;
var hi = nodeList.children
var i;
for (i = 0; i < hi.length; i++) {
  hi[i].classList.add('square')
}

for (i = 0; i < hi.length; i++) {
  var positionNo = document.createTextNode(''+i+'')
  hi[i].appendChild(positionNo)
}


//SNAKE

//var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99) + 1

var x = 22


function control(e) {
var plug = e.key
console.log('position is '+x)

var leftBorder = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
var topBorder = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
var bottomBorder = [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
var rightBorder = [9, 19, 29, 39, 49, 59, 69, 79, 89, 99]

console.log('NEW KEY')

console.log(plug)

if (e.key == 'ArrowRight'){     //SNAKE MOVE RIGHT
  for (let i=0; i<10; i++){
   setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('right')
    x+=1 
    if(x>100){
     location.reload()
    }else{}
    console.log('x is '+x)
    hi[x].classList.add('snake')
   }, 1000 * i);
   setTimeout(function() {
    hi[x-1].classList.remove('snake')
      }, 1000 * i);
      setTimeout(function() {
        if (leftBorder.includes(x) ||
        topBorder.includes(x) || 
            bottomBorder.includes(x) ||  
            rightBorder.includes(x)
           ){ 
             alert('LOST')
        } else{
          console.log(x)
        }
      }, 1000 * i);
      
      
    }
}
  
  
  else if (e.key == 'ArrowDown'){    //SNAKE MOVE DOWN
    for (let i=0; i<x+9; i++){
        setTimeout(function() {
          console.log('down')
          x+=10 
        if(x>100){
          location.reload()
          }else{
          }
          hi[x].classList.add('snake')
          console.log('x is '+x)
      }, 1000 * i);
        setTimeout(function() {
          hi[x-10].classList.remove('snake')
        }, 1000 * i);
        setTimeout(function() {
          if (leftBorder.includes(x) ||
          topBorder.includes(x) || 
              bottomBorder.includes(x) ||  
              rightBorder.includes(x)
            ){ 
              alert('LOST')
          } else{
            console.log(x)
          }
        }, 1000 * i);  
      }     
  }
      
 
 
  else if (e.key == 'ArrowUp'){    //SNAKE MOVE UP
   for (let i=0; i<10; i++){
       setTimeout(function() {
         console.log('before decrement'+x)
       x-=10 
       if(x<0){
         location.reload()
         }else{
         }
       
       console.log('after decrement '+x)
       hi[x].classList.add('snake')
       }, 1000 * i);
       setTimeout(function() {
         hi[x+10].classList.remove('snake')
         console.log('after classremove '+x)
       }, 1000 * i);
       setTimeout(function() {
         if (leftBorder.includes(x) ||
             topBorder.includes(x) || 
             bottomBorder.includes(x) ||  
             rightBorder.includes(x)
            ){ 
              alert('LOST')
           } else{
             
           }
         }, 1000 * i);  
       }     
       
  }
    
 
  else if (e.key == 'ArrowLeft') {   //SNAKE MOVE LEFT
      for (let i=0; i<x+9; i++){
      setTimeout(function() {
      x-=1 
      if(x<0){
        location.reload()
        }else{
        }
      
      hi[x].classList.add('snake')
      console.log('x is '+x)
    }, 1000 * i);
      setTimeout(function() {
        hi[x+1].classList.remove('snake')
      }, 1000 * i);
      setTimeout(function() {
        if (leftBorder.includes(x) ||
        topBorder.includes(x) || 
        bottomBorder.includes(x) ||  
            rightBorder.includes(x)
            ){ 
             alert('LOST')
        } else{
          console.log(x)
        }
      }, 1000 * i);  
    }     
    
  }
    
    
  
console.log('HIIIIIIIIII')
 
    
}    
    

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
}

body{
 height: 100vh;
}

#game-board{
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 200px;
 height:200px;
 border: black solid;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.snake{
 background-color: blueviolet;
}

.square{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 border:1px cadetblue solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="game-board">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
 </div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
document.addEventListener("keyup",control)
```

How do i make it just go one direction after every event.

Comment: The quick fix is to use `clearInterval` to cancel existing ones. The proper solution is to use a single Interval and handle all the movement in there. The idea is that a single keypress will only change the current direction of the snake, while the interval function handles its movement independently. This will also remove tons of duplicate code.

Comment: The way you're doing it is really unstable and you make it hard on yourself. You should have a central interval that moves the snake, while you keep track the keys pressed separately of that.

Comment: Here's my take: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/8krjz7ng/

Comment: @AntonCurmanschii Isn't that exactly what I said, just with different words?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider setting some variables, ie, `var s1;  var s2;` at the top and don't set them as anything, then in your snake move function, set that specific setInterval as the variable, then clear all the other set intervals except the one you want to run.

I am not great at explaining this but you can see a demo below. Basically, it stops the setInterval, stopping your snake from going in that direction and allows it to go in another.

```js
var s1;
var x = 0;
s1 = setInterval(function() { //When you set your setInterval as a variable you can stop it using clearInterval([the var name]);
  x++;
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = x;
}, 1000);

function stop() {
  clearInterval(s1);
}

function continue1() {
  s1 = setInterval(function() {
    x++;
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = x;
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<p id="text">0</p>
<button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
<button onclick="continue1()">Continue</button>
```

I don't know if this is the answer your looking for, but this might help.

Comment: LOL I forgot to add a "1" to my button function. LOL

Comment: Thanks man, I ll check this out. @JSman225

Comment: just remember, if you use this method, remember to set your variables as global variables. I can't relate how much time I waste wondering why my program doesn't work, and that's usually the problem. :)